# Knapsack - determining set from total value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

After seeing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h6Fi6AQiRM) lecture I created the following knapsack code. In the lecture, the professor says it will be easy to determine the set from the optimal value (minute 19:00), however I can not find how to do it. I provide an example in the code which sums the values to 21, how can I determine the set (in this case 12, 7, 2) from this value?

```js
/*
    v = value
    w = weight
    c = capacity
 */
function knapsack(v, w, c) {
    var n = v.length,
        table = [];
    // create two-dimensional array to hold values in memory
    while (table.length <= c) {
        table.push([]);
    }

    return ks(c, 0);
    function ks(c, i) {
        if (i >= n) {
            table[c][i] = 0;
            return table[c][i];
        }
        if (c < w[i]) {
            if (table[c][i+1] === undefined) {
                table[c][i + 1] = ks(c, i + 1);
            }
            return table[c][i + 1];
        }
        else {
            if (table[c][i + 1] === undefined) {
                table[c][i + 1] = ks(c, i + 1);
            }
            if (table[c - w[i]][i + 1] === undefined) {
                table[c - w[i]][i + 1] = ks(c - w[i], i + 1);
            }
            return Math.max(table[c][i + 1], v[i] + table[c - w[i]][i + 1]);
        }
    }
}

//This is a test case
var v = [7, 2, 1, 6, 12];
var w = [3, 1, 2, 4, 6];
var c = 10;
var result = knapsack(v, w, c);
document.getElementById("solution").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<pre>Optimal solution value is: <span id="solution"></span></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not easy at all. Determining whether a subset of some set of numbers has a certain sum is known as the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and it is NP-complete, just like knapsack itself. It would be a lot easier to just keep pointers to the solution of the subproblem from which you constructed the optimal solution to a larger subproblem. That way you can just walk back along the pointers from the globally optimal solution to find the actual set that gave you the optimal value.

(EDIT: as noted in the comments by j_random_hacker, once we have the DP table, we can actually determine the set that gave the optimal value in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, by starting from the optimal solution and working backwards through the table, consider each possible item that could have been the last item added and checking if that solution matches the expected value.)

On a different note, I'd recommend watching some different lectures. The guy makes some strange claims, like that O(nc) -- n number of items, c capacity -- is much less than O(2<sup>n</sup>), which is simply not true when c is large. (In fact, this is called a [pseudo-polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) solution, and it is still exponential in the length of the input, measured in bits.)

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would add pointers to the solution in this code?

Comment: @user3836205 Instead of storing only a number, you could store objects with a parent, item and value. Here value would be the number you're currently already calculating, parent would be the solution to the subproblem you expanded to get the solution to your current subproblem, and item would just be the item you added.

Comment: I haven't watched the lecture, but I want to say that the precise wording is important here.  Determining the subset from just the number is indeed NP-hard as you say, but determining the subset using only *an algorithm for finding the number* can be said to be "easy" in the sense that it's only "polynomially harder" than finding a single number: ...

Comment: ... Let the original solution be y_0 and the original capacity be c_0.  Remove some item x_i, reduce the capacity by w_i and solve it.  If the answer = y - v_i, then x_i is part of some optimal solution, and you should leave the capacity at c_0 - w_i; otherwise it's not, and you should set the capacity back to c_0.  Either way, x_i gets removed.  Keep removing single items and re-solving until none remain.  This takes n times the time to solve a single instance.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: the lecturer literally says "once we know what the [optimal] value is, it's very easy to go back over our calculations and figure out what [the] set was".

Comment: @JordiVermeulen: I can't watch the video as I'm at work, but it sounds to me like he means "once we know what the [optimal] value is, it's very easy to go back over our calculations and figure out what [the] set was *[by using the DP table]*", and this is also true.  Instead of maintaining backpointers as you suggest, you can alternatively look at all O(n) possible previous states of the final state, recalculate their successor states and pick any one of them that leads to the optimal final state.  This is n times slower than using backpointers, but only involves solving the problem once.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen: In fact, keeping backpointers as you suggest can be thought of as a way of caching this process.  Without backpointers, recovering an optimal subset is O(n^2); with them it's just O(n), but you need an additional O(nc) space to hold the pointers (which usually isn't a big deal, since you need O(nc) space for the DP table anyway).